# php array data in mysql

Tags: php, arrays, mysql, mysqli

I am very new to mysql and php. I need to put an array from php into a data table:

The array looks like this:

```
$memberdata
    Key    value
    apple  5
    banana 8
    salmon 3
    candle 4
    ..........
    and 100 more...
```

My mysql table looks like this:

```
MemberTable
    ID(INT11)=PK    MemID(INT11)      stuff(varchar)     value(INT2)
    1               23                apple              5
    2               23                banana             8
    3               23                salmon             3
    4               23                candle             4
    5               45                banana             1
    6               45                apple              9
```

So each member; here member 23 and 45 can have the same stuff but with other values, so for every member i have one php array of data. (mysql ID is auto increment).

My question: is there a possibility to store an array directly into a mysql table...?
In a book that i read they make a foreach loop and in the loop they open a connection to the database... so i thought that is maybe to time consuming:

book example:

```
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
$MemID = "23";
$query_pre = "INSERT INTO MemberTable ('MemID','stuff','value') VALUES (";
Foreach ($memberdata as $stuff => $value)
{
 $query = $query_pre . "$MemID,$stuff,$value)"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query");
}
```

Regards,
Thijs

Comment: Using a foreach is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's very strange book.
Although idea in general is right, this particular code contains both PHP and mysql errors.

it should be something like this (not tested):

```
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
$MemID = "23";
$prequery = array();
Foreach ($memberdata as $stuff => $value)
{
  $stuff = mysqli_real_escape_string($stuff);
  $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
  $prequery[] = "($MemID,'$stuff','$value')"; 
} 
$query = "INSERT INTO MemberTable (MemID,stuff,value) VALUES ".implode(",",$prequery);
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($cxn).$query);
```

Comment: Hi, does this implode function puts all the data in one string, and then in one datacell in MySQL? Because the array can exceed 8000 characters (longtext)

Comment: @Thijs yes, obviously. Try to read function descriptions at least. Or you won't learn anything. However, Mysql default data packet is 2M. check if your final query fits into it (hint: strlen())

Comment: I didn't need to get all the data in one string... the database must be searchable afterwards... My question was if it was possible to store an array in a database but also in the correct place and not as one string in a cell and later explode it back into php... I am reading the serialize - unserialize part of php manual, but, if i am correct it puts an array in a standarized way into a string, ready for mysql... and that you can unserialize it later so that it is readable for php (puts it back in the array variable again..) I know i have a lot to learn... sorry!

Comment: @Thijs I was speaking not of data cell but of data packet. As for the cells, it's okay. I see your problem now. You don't know what SQL QUERY you need, but asking for PHP CODE to produce it. Learn SQL first. As for my code it's okay, it works as you need. It performs MANY inserts using just one query string

Comment: Thank you for having so much patience... Do you have any tips for a good mysql book... (i've read php / mysql for dummies.. i know!!) if i understand your code correct you can insert a lot of data in one query as a packet, so first you put all the data in (in this case) 3 arrays $prequery[] = "($MemID,'$stuff','$value')"; and then out of the "foreach" loop you put it in the VALUES, and u use .implode to put the 3 arrays together...

Comment: @Thijs  not 3 arrays but 3 strings. the goal is to get a query like this (for example): `INSERT INTO MemberTable (MemID,stuff,value) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)` so, first we get an array of strings `(1,2,3)` then implode it to get `(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)` and then adding it to the query

Comment: I want to but my query is to complicated... sometimes it needs more entries sometimes less... i am going to post a new question, because i'm going crazy again on this complicated string...

Answer (score 1):

The implementation you've written above is the most efficient way I'm aware of getting your data into the table.  One thing you might want to consider is making sure that the record's not a duplicate of an already-existing record before inserting it.  There are various ways to do that, including (this is not the most efficient way, but it works) clearing out that part of the table before doing the insert, doing a select query with a conditional run of your insert if its record count is 0, or using the INSERT OR UPDATE syntax, found here: [MySQL reference docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html).

I hope this helps!

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

You avoided the big mistake of running a separate insert query for each associated array element. That is what a lot of beginners do and it is extremely inefficient when using this PHP MySQL extension. This statement comes with the assumption that you are doing one transaction per query.

Since this is only one query, this is about as efficient as you can get. If you were to find a different PHP MySQL extension (i.e. PDO) that had a function to take an array like you have here, all it would be doing in the background is generated this huge query for you then executing it.

So, in short, you're doing it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach to insertion is correct, but your data isn't normalized. Keep this in mind if your table sizes begin to get too huge.  Your MemID and StuffID would be the unique key.

Answer (score -1):

Kind of an odd way to store the information for the users.

You can store the array directly in a single row.  Use the serialize function, like $sqlinput = serialize($array) and insert $sqlinput into the DB for that user.  Then when recalling it from the DB, use unserialize().  Alternatively, you could implode the array into a single string, and then insert it into the db, and then explode it again when recalling it.

Comment: I can't find a good example about the serialize function yet... But is this serialize function a function, which puts the whole column right in the database? so without the need of a foreach loop??